# Do linear transformations of convergent sequences converge?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ where $E, F$ are two normed vector spaces **(not necessarily finite or complete (Banach))**.  Is it true that if $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in $E$, is it true that $Tx_{n} \rightarrow y \in F$?

I know that it is true in finite dimensions that $Tx_{n} \rightarrow Tx$, and that we have a similar result for weakly converging sequences, so I'm assuming that there is a counterexample.  I just can't find one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how these help me out.

Comment: An operator satisfies the condition you're interested in if and only if it is bounded. If it's not bounded you can find a convergent sequence where applying the operator yields a divergent sequence.

Comment: I don't feel qualified to answer the question, but consider the convergent sequence $\sin(nx)/n$ on the space of smooth real valued functions on the unit interval. What happens when you take the derivative?